# 'System.Web.HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'GetOwinContext'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

I have the following error :'System.Web.HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'GetOwinContext' 
whenever I debug my project. this error is in the web API page, although it doesn't show an error in the default AccounController.cs and the nuget package is installed.what is missing?

```
using IdentitySample.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using task.Models;
using System.Globalization;
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ok I found the solution since I already installed the nuget package all I have to do is the following:

```
  return _userManager ?? HttpContext.**current**.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

Comment: which Nuget package did you install?

Comment: `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`

Comment: I was missing the current property on it, interestingly the examples I found on OWIN all had issues like this